# Upgrading Windows 10 to the 2021H1 update with only 32GB of disk

Tags: windows-10, windows-10-upgrade

I've got a machine that unfortunately only has a 32GB SSD.
It was sold bundled with Windows 10 so I was assuming this would work just fine.

However I'm unable to install the latest 2021H1 cummulative update and can't free up any more space on drive C:.

I've got plenty of space on other drives, but Windows insists on having more free Space on C:. I did try all Windows tools to clean up disk space but almost everything seems to be occupied by Windows and it doesn't want to remove anything.

Comment: Even with a 64GB flash drive which also has been sold is not enough to be able to get updates after the initial one. That was a bad selling strategy. @John is right, I would recommend to migrate the OS to a larger drive. Ask someone who knows what he/she is doing if you don't feel comfortable doing it yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, your C: drive is too small and likely needs to be replaced to allow Windows 10 21H1 and then beyond. So the answer here is a larger C: Drive.

Second, try the following:

1. Move documents and email from your Users folder to your other drive.
2. Remove all the files you can in c:\users\you\appdata\local\temp ; c:\windows\temp  ; and C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution\Download
3. Now run Disk Cleanup again.  This time, in the first Disk Cleanup screen, select Clean up System Files and let it run. Now select ALL items for cleanup including Prior Windows Installs (windows.old).

When done all the above try restarting and updating again.

Most likely you need a bigger drive.

Comment: While I appreciate your answer and admit that it might be the right think to do for most folks this is not what I'm going to do. I should probably try to return the computer since it obviously wasn't sold in a way that it can be used for more than a year (the legal minimum in my jurisdiction is 2y). But more likely I'll just install Linux. Thanks for the help still!

Comment: If you can return it or get the drive upgraded, that may be worth your while.